# Parameter 'from' in python3: formal parameter name expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using `click` in Python3:

```
@click.option('--param1', help="param1")
@click.option('--param2', help="param2")
@click.option('--from', help="from where..")
```

I want to use it in my main:

```
def main(param1, param2, from):
..
```

It works fine for `param1` and `param2` but for `from` I receive an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
formal parameter name expected
```

I think because the word from will probably also have another usage in python?
How can I make it work so I can use 'from' as a parameter?

Comment: Typically you'd use e.g. `from_` as the parameter name to avoid conflicts with keywords. The duplicate provides options for renaming arguments in `click` specifically.

Comment: `from` is a keyword in Python. I'm not familiar with click, but normally name clashes are avoided by adding a trailing underscore, i.e. `from_`.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll check immediately if it works with click too.

Comment: It seems I need to find a way in click to make --from translate to from_

Comment: @jonrsharpe duplicate indeed: `@click.option('--from', 'from_', help="xxx")` works